# Chernoff bounds and Binomial random variable

Tags: probability, self-study, probability-inequalities

If $N$ is a binomial random variable with parameters $n$ and $p$, it follows from the Chernoff bounds that $P(|N-np|\geq a) \leq 2e^{-2a^2/n}$

But when $p$ is small, the preceding Chernoff type bound can be improved to yield the following

$P(|N-np|\geq a)\leq 2e^{\frac{-a^2}{3np}}$

I do not understand the final inequality.Where can i get its proof?

Comment: What do you mean by "small"?

Comment: P is small that means I think  ${p\to0}$ but author has not specifically mentioned about that.

Comment: Where can I get the proof of final inequality?